# How to create all possible groupings of elements as list of lists in Python

Tags: python, combinations, nested-lists

Suppose I have the following list:

`data= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']`

How can I create all possible groups of 3 lists without repeats in each group? Example output will be:

```
[[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']],[['a','b','e'],['c','d','g'],['f','h','i']]...] etc
```

EDIT: There should be no repeats in the code. For example,  if the code outputs `[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]` 
then it shouldnt output variants like
`[['a','b','c'],['g','h','i'],['d','e','f']]` or `[['c','b','a'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]`

Comment: @PM2Ring Sorry I ddnt clarify this. If the code outputs `[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]` then it shouldnt output variants like `[['a','b','c'],['g','h','i'],['d','e','f']]`or `[['c','b','a'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]`. Thanks

Comment: So is it OK to return groups of 3 sets, or do we need to put them back into lists and in the original order?

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure I got what you were asking for correctly. Can you tell us how many results you expect? Or, maybe even better, do the 2x2 version and exhaustively list them?

Comment: @abarnert Sets will be great too. I'm not sure how many combinations of groups there are, I just need all possible groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to attack this is to treat it as an [Exact Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) problem. As Wikipedia mentions, the standard way to solve such problems is with Knuth's Algorithm X. In other languages that's implemented using Knuth's "Dancing Links" algorithm. We could do that in Python, but it gets a bit tedious since we don't have pointers. But Ali Assaf has shown how to do Algorithm X using Python's `dict` and `set` objects.

The code below performs the desired partitioning, without repetitions, maintaining the order of the letters used in the `data` string.

```
"""
    Partition a list into equal parts

    Uses Knuth's Algorithm X for the exact cover problem.
    The Algorithm X code, using dicts instead of doubly-linked
    circular lists was written by Ali Assaf.
    See http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~aassaf9/python/algorithm_x.html
    and http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~aassaf9/python/sudoku.txt
"""

from itertools import product, combinations

#Algorithm X functions
def solve(X, Y, solution):
    if X:
        c = min(X, key=lambda c: len(X[c]))
        for r in list(X[c]):
            solution.append(r)
            cols = select(X, Y, r)
            yield from solve(X, Y, solution)
            deselect(X, Y, r, cols)
            solution.pop()
    else:
        yield list(solution)

def select(X, Y, r):
    cols = []
    for j in Y[r]:
        for i in X[j]:
            for k in Y[i]:
                if k != j:
                    X[k].remove(i)
        cols.append(X.pop(j))
    return cols

def deselect(X, Y, r, cols):
    for j in reversed(Y[r]):
        X[j] = cols.pop()
        for i in X[j]:
            for k in Y[i]:
                if k != j:
                    X[k].add(i)

#Invert subset collection
def exact_cover(X, Y):
    newX = {j: set() for j in X}
    for i, row in Y.items():
        for j in row:
            newX[j].add(i)
    return newX

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

data = 'abcdefghi'
Y = {''.join(t): t for t in combinations(data, 3)}
X = exact_cover(data, Y)

for i, solution in enumerate(solve(X, Y, []), 1):
    print(i, solution)
```

**output**

```
1 ['aei', 'bgh', 'cdf']
2 ['aei', 'bch', 'dfg']
3 ['aei', 'bcf', 'dgh']
4 ['aei', 'bfh', 'cdg']
5 ['aei', 'bcg', 'dfh']
6 ['aei', 'bdg', 'cfh']
7 ['aei', 'bfg', 'cdh']
8 ['aei', 'bdf', 'cgh']
9 ['aei', 'bdh', 'cfg']
10 ['aei', 'bcd', 'fgh']
11 ['abf', 'cgh', 'dei']
12 ['abf', 'ceh', 'dgi']
13 ['abf', 'dgh', 'cei']
14 ['abf', 'cdh', 'egi']
15 ['abf', 'chi', 'deg']
16 ['abf', 'egh', 'cdi']
17 ['abf', 'ghi', 'cde']
18 ['abf', 'deh', 'cgi']
19 ['abf', 'ehi', 'cdg']
20 ['abf', 'dhi', 'ceg']
21 ['ace', 'bgh', 'dfi']
22 ['ace', 'dgi', 'bfh']
23 ['ace', 'dgh', 'bfi']
24 ['ace', 'dfg', 'bhi']
25 ['ace', 'fgh', 'bdi']
26 ['ace', 'fgi', 'bdh']
27 ['ace', 'ghi', 'bdf']
28 ['ace', 'bdg', 'fhi']
29 ['ace', 'bfg', 'dhi']
30 ['ace', 'bgi', 'dfh']
31 ['ach', 'dfi', 'beg']
32 ['ach', 'dfg', 'bei']
33 ['ach', 'bfi', 'deg']
34 ['ach', 'def', 'bgi']
35 ['ach', 'fgi', 'bde']
36 ['ach', 'efg', 'bdi']
37 ['ach', 'efi', 'bdg']
38 ['ach', 'bfg', 'dei']
39 ['ach', 'bdf', 'egi']
40 ['ach', 'bef', 'dgi']
41 ['afh', 'bei', 'cdg']
42 ['afh', 'dgi', 'bce']
43 ['afh', 'egi', 'bcd']
44 ['afh', 'cei', 'bdg']
45 ['afh', 'cgi', 'bde']
46 ['afh', 'dei', 'bcg']
47 ['afh', 'bdi', 'ceg']
48 ['afh', 'bgi', 'cde']
49 ['afh', 'bci', 'deg']
50 ['afh', 'cdi', 'beg']
51 ['aci', 'deg', 'bfh']
52 ['aci', 'bgh', 'def']
53 ['aci', 'beg', 'dfh']
54 ['aci', 'dgh', 'bef']
55 ['aci', 'dfg', 'beh']
56 ['aci', 'fgh', 'bde']
57 ['aci', 'bdg', 'efh']
58 ['aci', 'efg', 'bdh']
59 ['aci', 'bfg', 'deh']
60 ['aci', 'egh', 'bdf']
61 ['abh', 'dfi', 'ceg']
62 ['abh', 'cef', 'dgi']
63 ['abh', 'cfi', 'deg']
64 ['abh', 'dfg', 'cei']
65 ['abh', 'def', 'cgi']
66 ['abh', 'fgi', 'cde']
67 ['abh', 'efg', 'cdi']
68 ['abh', 'efi', 'cdg']
69 ['abh', 'cfg', 'dei']
70 ['abh', 'cdf', 'egi']
71 ['ahi', 'cdg', 'bef']
72 ['ahi', 'deg', 'bcf']
73 ['ahi', 'ceg', 'bdf']
74 ['ahi', 'beg', 'cdf']
75 ['ahi', 'dfg', 'bce']
76 ['ahi', 'bcg', 'def']
77 ['ahi', 'bdg', 'cef']
78 ['ahi', 'efg', 'bcd']
79 ['ahi', 'bfg', 'cde']
80 ['ahi', 'cfg', 'bde']
81 ['adi', 'cef', 'bgh']
82 ['adi', 'ceg', 'bfh']
83 ['adi', 'bce', 'fgh']
84 ['adi', 'beg', 'cfh']
85 ['adi', 'ceh', 'bfg']
86 ['adi', 'efh', 'bcg']
87 ['adi', 'beh', 'cfg']
88 ['adi', 'efg', 'bch']
89 ['adi', 'bef', 'cgh']
90 ['adi', 'egh', 'bcf']
91 ['acg', 'dfi', 'beh']
92 ['acg', 'bfh', 'dei']
93 ['acg', 'fhi', 'bde']
94 ['acg', 'bfi', 'deh']
95 ['acg', 'efh', 'bdi']
96 ['acg', 'def', 'bhi']
97 ['acg', 'efi', 'bdh']
98 ['acg', 'bdf', 'ehi']
99 ['acg', 'bef', 'dhi']
100 ['acg', 'dfh', 'bei']
101 ['acd', 'bei', 'fgh']
102 ['acd', 'egi', 'bfh']
103 ['acd', 'fhi', 'beg']
104 ['acd', 'bfi', 'egh']
105 ['acd', 'fgi', 'beh']
106 ['acd', 'ghi', 'bef']
107 ['acd', 'efi', 'bgh']
108 ['acd', 'ehi', 'bfg']
109 ['acd', 'bhi', 'efg']
110 ['acd', 'bgi', 'efh']
111 ['aeg', 'cfh', 'bdi']
112 ['aeg', 'bch', 'dfi']
113 ['aeg', 'chi', 'bdf']
114 ['aeg', 'cdh', 'bfi']
115 ['aeg', 'bfh', 'cdi']
116 ['aeg', 'fhi', 'bcd']
117 ['aeg', 'bhi', 'cdf']
118 ['aeg', 'bdh', 'cfi']
119 ['aeg', 'dfh', 'bci']
120 ['aeg', 'dhi', 'bcf']
121 ['abc', 'dfi', 'egh']
122 ['abc', 'dfg', 'ehi']
123 ['abc', 'fgh', 'dei']
124 ['abc', 'fhi', 'deg']
125 ['abc', 'efh', 'dgi']
126 ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
127 ['abc', 'fgi', 'deh']
128 ['abc', 'efg', 'dhi']
129 ['abc', 'efi', 'dgh']
130 ['abc', 'dfh', 'egi']
131 ['abg', 'dfi', 'ceh']
132 ['abg', 'cfi', 'deh']
133 ['abg', 'chi', 'def']
134 ['abg', 'cei', 'dfh']
135 ['abg', 'fhi', 'cde']
136 ['abg', 'dei', 'cfh']
137 ['abg', 'efi', 'cdh']
138 ['abg', 'ehi', 'cdf']
139 ['abg', 'cdi', 'efh']
140 ['abg', 'dhi', 'cef']
141 ['adf', 'bei', 'cgh']
142 ['adf', 'ceg', 'bhi']
143 ['adf', 'bce', 'ghi']
144 ['adf', 'ceh', 'bgi']
145 ['adf', 'beg', 'chi']
146 ['adf', 'egi', 'bch']
147 ['adf', 'cei', 'bgh']
148 ['adf', 'beh', 'cgi']
149 ['adf', 'ehi', 'bcg']
150 ['adf', 'egh', 'bci']
151 ['agi', 'cfh', 'bde']
152 ['agi', 'cef', 'bdh']
153 ['agi', 'bch', 'def']
154 ['agi', 'bce', 'dfh']
155 ['agi', 'ceh', 'bdf']
156 ['agi', 'cde', 'bfh']
157 ['agi', 'bcf', 'deh']
158 ['agi', 'cdh', 'bef']
159 ['agi', 'bcd', 'efh']
160 ['agi', 'cdf', 'beh']
161 ['abi', 'cfh', 'deg']
162 ['abi', 'cgh', 'def']
163 ['abi', 'ceh', 'dfg']
164 ['abi', 'dgh', 'cef']
165 ['abi', 'cdh', 'efg']
166 ['abi', 'fgh', 'cde']
167 ['abi', 'efh', 'cdg']
168 ['abi', 'egh', 'cdf']
169 ['abi', 'deh', 'cfg']
170 ['abi', 'dfh', 'ceg']
171 ['aeh', 'cdg', 'bfi']
172 ['aeh', 'dgi', 'bcf']
173 ['aeh', 'dfg', 'bci']
174 ['aeh', 'cgi', 'bdf']
175 ['aeh', 'fgi', 'bcd']
176 ['aeh', 'bcg', 'dfi']
177 ['aeh', 'bdg', 'cfi']
178 ['aeh', 'bfg', 'cdi']
179 ['aeh', 'bgi', 'cdf']
180 ['aeh', 'cfg', 'bdi']
181 ['ade', 'cfi', 'bgh']
182 ['ade', 'chi', 'bfg']
183 ['ade', 'fhi', 'bcg']
184 ['ade', 'bfi', 'cgh']
185 ['ade', 'cgi', 'bfh']
186 ['ade', 'fgi', 'bch']
187 ['ade', 'ghi', 'bcf']
188 ['ade', 'bhi', 'cfg']
189 ['ade', 'bgi', 'cfh']
190 ['ade', 'bci', 'fgh']
191 ['afi', 'bgh', 'cde']
192 ['afi', 'cgh', 'bde']
193 ['afi', 'bch', 'deg']
194 ['afi', 'ceh', 'bdg']
195 ['afi', 'dgh', 'bce']
196 ['afi', 'cdh', 'beg']
197 ['afi', 'beh', 'cdg']
198 ['afi', 'deh', 'bcg']
199 ['afi', 'bdh', 'ceg']
200 ['afi', 'egh', 'bcd']
201 ['adh', 'cef', 'bgi']
202 ['adh', 'ceg', 'bfi']
203 ['adh', 'bce', 'fgi']
204 ['adh', 'cfi', 'beg']
205 ['adh', 'bcf', 'egi']
206 ['adh', 'cei', 'bfg']
207 ['adh', 'cgi', 'bef']
208 ['adh', 'bcg', 'efi']
209 ['adh', 'bci', 'efg']
210 ['adh', 'cfg', 'bei']
211 ['abd', 'cfi', 'egh']
212 ['abd', 'chi', 'efg']
213 ['abd', 'egi', 'cfh']
214 ['abd', 'cei', 'fgh']
215 ['abd', 'fhi', 'ceg']
216 ['abd', 'cgi', 'efh']
217 ['abd', 'fgi', 'ceh']
218 ['abd', 'ghi', 'cef']
219 ['abd', 'efi', 'cgh']
220 ['abd', 'ehi', 'cfg']
221 ['acf', 'deg', 'bhi']
222 ['acf', 'bgh', 'dei']
223 ['acf', 'dgi', 'beh']
224 ['acf', 'beg', 'dhi']
225 ['acf', 'dgh', 'bei']
226 ['acf', 'egi', 'bdh']
227 ['acf', 'ghi', 'bde']
228 ['acf', 'bdg', 'ehi']
229 ['acf', 'bgi', 'deh']
230 ['acf', 'egh', 'bdi']
231 ['abe', 'dfi', 'cgh']
232 ['abe', 'dgi', 'cfh']
233 ['abe', 'cfi', 'dgh']
234 ['abe', 'chi', 'dfg']
235 ['abe', 'fhi', 'cdg']
236 ['abe', 'cgi', 'dfh']
237 ['abe', 'fgi', 'cdh']
238 ['abe', 'ghi', 'cdf']
239 ['abe', 'cdi', 'fgh']
240 ['abe', 'dhi', 'cfg']
241 ['adg', 'cfh', 'bei']
242 ['adg', 'cef', 'bhi']
243 ['adg', 'cfi', 'beh']
244 ['adg', 'bcf', 'ehi']
245 ['adg', 'bfh', 'cei']
246 ['adg', 'fhi', 'bce']
247 ['adg', 'bfi', 'ceh']
248 ['adg', 'efh', 'bci']
249 ['adg', 'efi', 'bch']
250 ['adg', 'bef', 'chi']
251 ['agh', 'bei', 'cdf']
252 ['agh', 'dfi', 'bce']
253 ['agh', 'cfi', 'bde']
254 ['agh', 'cei', 'bdf']
255 ['agh', 'bfi', 'cde']
256 ['agh', 'dei', 'bcf']
257 ['agh', 'efi', 'bcd']
258 ['agh', 'bdi', 'cef']
259 ['agh', 'bci', 'def']
260 ['agh', 'cdi', 'bef']
261 ['afg', 'bei', 'cdh']
262 ['afg', 'bce', 'dhi']
263 ['afg', 'ceh', 'bdi']
264 ['afg', 'cde', 'bhi']
265 ['afg', 'cei', 'bdh']
266 ['afg', 'bde', 'chi']
267 ['afg', 'beh', 'cdi']
268 ['afg', 'deh', 'bci']
269 ['afg', 'dei', 'bch']
270 ['afg', 'ehi', 'bcd']
271 ['aef', 'cdg', 'bhi']
272 ['aef', 'dgi', 'bch']
273 ['aef', 'dgh', 'bci']
274 ['aef', 'cdh', 'bgi']
275 ['aef', 'bdg', 'chi']
276 ['aef', 'bdh', 'cgi']
277 ['aef', 'bdi', 'cgh']
278 ['aef', 'cdi', 'bgh']
279 ['aef', 'dhi', 'bcg']
280 ['aef', 'bcd', 'ghi']
```

Note that Algorithm X is not necessarily the most efficient way to find a solution to a given problem. In many cases a more specific solution will have better performance.

Comment: This definitely gives the sort of output I was looking for. Is it possible to change the code so the output is of the form [['a','e','i]', ['b','g','h'], ['c','d','f']] etc. Thanks

Comment: @West Certainly! Just before the final `print` line insert this line: `solution = [list(u) for u in solution]`.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

One obvious thing to do is to do three nested choose-3 loops. (Well, two, because the last one will be choosing 3 out of 3…)

If your input is dynamic length, I'd do this with `product` or with recursion, but I think for the 3x3 case, it may be simpler to loop explicitly:

```
def part3s(data):
    data = set(data)
    for c1 in combinations(data, 3):
        for c2 in combinations(data-set(c1), 3):
            yield (c1, c2, data-set(c1)-set(c2))
for part3 in part3s(data):
    print(part3)
```

Comment: I got a Syntax error on running the code: `'yield' outside function`

Comment: @West Yes, this is meant to be the body of a function. I'll edit to show how to use it if it's not obvious enough; sorry.

Comment: This code gives repeats which isnt what I was looking for. For example it outputs `(('d', 'c', 'g'), ('e', 'b', 'a'), {'h', 'i', 'f'})` as well as `(('e', 'b', 'a'), ('d', 'c', 'g'), {'h', 'i', 'f'}`

Comment: @West That's why I was trying too figure out if you wanted 1680, 560, or 280 results—there's three or four different ways to interpret "no repeats", and I wasn't sure which one you wanted. I think you want [PM2Ring's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50325736/908494).

Comment: Sure yeh I figured I hadnt clarified enough, sorry. PM2Ring's is almost what I'm looking though I cant figure out how to convert each list to a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
data= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
d=itertools.permutations(data,9)
for i in d:print(i[:3],i[3:6],i[6:])
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants all those repeats, although it's not at all clear.

Answer (score 0):

input data

```
data= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
```

create all elements permutations and par them into groups of 3

```
permutation_list = permutations(data, 3)
```

create list of all grouped elements

```
out = []
for i in permutation_list:
    out.append(i)
```

split list again into group of 3

```
def split(out_list, count):
    return [out_list[i::count] for i in range(count)]

result = split(out, int(len(out)/3))
```

Output:

```
[[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'a', 'b'), ('g', 'a', 'b')], [('a', 'b', 'd'), ('d', 'a', 'c'), ('g', 'a', 'c')],.....
```

Comment: That's not what the OP wants. Eg, your `[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'a', 'b'), ('g', 'a', 'b')]` doesn't cover all the letters from 'a' to 'i', and it repeats 'a' and 'b'.